# how to use razor code in typescript instead of javascript

Tags: typescript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my `.chstml` code

```
@using MyProject.Constant.MyConstants
```

Inside `.chstml` , I use this constant value in javascript like

```
switch (value) {
    case @((int)MyConstants.ValueOne):
```

Now, I have to change this javascript to typescript file. I want to use those constant value in typescript.

How can I include the namespace `MyProject.Constant.MyConstants` inside typescript to use it?

Comment: You can use `data-` attribute in an element (e.g. `data-valueOne`) as replacement of direct usage with `$('#elementId').data('valueOne')` in TS side, but I want to know if you have separate .ts file to run the code.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto,  yes, `.ts` is in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that you can't use server-side objects (including C# namespaces) directly inside external `.ts` files (with Razor syntax), such like external JS files. However, you can create hidden element in CSHTML file which has `data-` attribute to hold the integer value:

```
<div id="valueone" data-valueone="@MyConstants.ValueOne" style="display:none">...</div>
```

And convert it as constant integer value inside external `.ts` file with `parseInt` (suppose jQuery is used):

```
var valueOne = parseInt($('#valueone').data('valueone'));
```

Then put that value inside `switch` block as a `case` condition:

```
switch (value) {
    case valueOne:
        // do something
        break;

    // other cases

    default:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

References:

[TypeScript Converting a String to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)

[TypeScript within .cshtml Razor Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429693/typescript-within-cshtml-razor-files)

[Pass value from c# to cshtml to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005858/pass-value-from-c-sharp-to-cshtml-to-typescript)